# Loop for nested template and dynamically get keyvault secret name

Tags: json, azure, azure-keyvault

Based on information from [Microsoft site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/key-vault-parameter?tabs=azure-cli), it is possible get key vault secrets during the implementation. I would like to have similar solution but for 5 VMs and reuse templates in Loop to create 5 VMs with different password from key vault. The key vault already exists with the secrets name. The secrets name are like: Secrets0...Secrets4.

Does anyone has any idea of how to do this? Below my solution with Loop but doesn't works for me.
I appreciate for your support.

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
      "location": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "The location where the resources will be deployed."
        }
      },
      "vaultName": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "The name of the keyvault that contains the secret."
        }
      },
      "secretName": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "The name of the secret."
        }
      },
      "vaultResourceGroupName": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "The name of the resource group that contains the keyvault."
        }
      },
      "vaultSubscription": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "[subscription().subscriptionId]",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "The name of the subscription that contains the keyvault."
        }
      }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2020-10-01",
      "name": "[concat('DynamicSecret,copyIndex('VMsLoop'))]"

      "copy": {
        "name": "VMsLoop",
        "count": 5,
        "mode": "Serial",
        "batchSize": 1
        },

      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "expressionEvaluationOptions": {
          "scope": "inner"
        },
        "template": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "parameters": {
            "adminLogin": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "adminPassword": {
              "type": "securestring"
            },
            "location": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "variables": {
            "sqlServerName": "[concat('sql-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id, 'sql'))]"
          },
          "resources": [
            {
              "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
              "apiVersion": "2018-06-01-preview",
              "name": "[variables('sqlServerName')]",
              "location": "[parameters('location')]",
              "properties": {
                "administratorLogin": "[parameters('adminLogin')]",
                "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
              }
            }
          ],
          "outputs": {
            "sqlFQDN": {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "[reference(variables('sqlServerName')).fullyQualifiedDomainName]"
            }
          }
        },
        "parameters": {
          "location": {
            "value": "[parameters('location')]"
          },
          "adminLogin": {
            "value": "ghuser"
          },
          "adminPassword": {
            "reference": {
              "keyVault": {
                "id": "[resourceId(parameters('vaultSubscription'), parameters('vaultResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', parameters('vaultName'))]"
              },
              "secretName": "[concat(parameters('secretName'),copyIndex('VMsLoop'))]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template you have provided actually works (except for one tiny typo - missing closing quote after DynamicSecret at `"[concat('DynamicSecret,copyIndex('VMsLoop'))]"` ).

However, since the `uniquestring` function that is used to generate the sql server name is [deterministic](https://www.codeisahighway.com/use-uniquestring-function-to-generate-unique-names-for-resources-in-arm-template/) (i.e. generated using the passed parameters of resoure group name and 'sql' string - `uniqueString(resourceGroup().id, 'sql')`. So the loop is hitting the same server instance just changing the password to the next secret in the list.

You can either promote the `sqlServerName` to parameter and suffix it with the loop index, or keep it as a variable and expand the uniqueString function with the deployment (i.e. `uniqueString(resourceGroup().id, deployment().name, 'sql')` ).